# Elements of list in terms of array indices using Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

How do I write elements of list `B` in terms of array indices of `A`? The desired output is attached.

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
B = [1,5,6]
```

The desired output is

```
B=[A[0,0], A[1,1], A[1,2]]
```

Comment: This works when ```B=[1,5,6]```. However, for ```B=[1,5,6,7]```, it says ```DeprecationWarning: elementwise comparison failed; this will raise an error in the future.```

Comment: `A[[0,1,1],[1,1,2]]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `numpy.isin` to see if the elements in `B` exist in `A`; then use `numpy.where` to find the indexes of the elements that exist. Since the indexes are separated by axes, you could finally, you could unpack and `zip` them to get the desired outcome:

```
out = list(zip(*np.where(np.isin(A, B))))
```

For `A=np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])` and `B=[1,5,6,7]`, the output:

```
[(0, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0)]
```